# Magento 2 (ver. 2.3.6) reindex not working

Tags: magento2, database, reindex

I have a single view Magento 2, with about 5000 products on it, running on a cloud hosting with 4GB RAM.

What happens is that every time the reindex process is triggered (by the cron job or by hand) it never ends and the website goes down (503 error).

I have checked the cPanel troubleshooting tool and it shows 2 queries being killed due to timeout, both trying to access the table MG_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE1.

So I tried to truncate the table but it's not working, the query fails and the e-commerce goes down during the process.

I have tried to reset index status with `php bin/magento indexer:reset`
I have tried to reset index status by changing the status to `invalid` directly in the db

but then, when I try the reindex it fails again.

Any guess?

Comment: any errors in the log files?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install newrelic agent and see which are the errors it picks up.